# uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to pass data from model to controller in codeigniter and get this error :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError
>   Message: Too few arguments to function Debitur::get_data_sms(), 0
>   passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sms_gateway_2\application\controllers\User.php on line
>   119 and exactly 3 expected
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\sms_gateway_2\application\models\Debitur.php
>
> Line Number: 9
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sms_gateway_2\application\controllers\User.php
>   Line: 119 Function: get_data_sms
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sms_gateway_2\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

This is my function in model (Debitur.php) :

```
    public function get_data_sms($nama_deb, $no_hp, $tunggakan)
      {  

    $array = array('nama_deb' => $nama_deb, 'no_hp' => $no_hp, 'tunggakan' => $tunggakan);
    $query = $this->db->getwhere('sms_debitur', $array);

    return $query->result();
      }
```

This is my function in controller (User.php) :

```
    public function sending_sms(){

    $this->load->library('bulkSms');

    $data= $this->debitur->get_data_sms();

    if ($data){
            $bulkSms = new bulkSms('***');

            $device = 111;
            $options = [];

            $number = $no_hp;
            $message = "To ".$nama_deb." payment ".$tunggakan."..";

            $result = $bulkSms->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $device, $options);

            if (count($result['response']['result']['success']) > 0) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success">Berhasil mengirim sms</div>');
            } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger">Gagal mengirim sms</div>');
            }

            redirect('user/send_sms', 'refresh');

    }
}
```

Comment: you are not passing any arguments to `get_data_sms`.

Comment: clearly `get_data_sms()` taks 3 arguments, you give it none

Comment: how to pass the arguments?

Comment: `$data= $this->debitur->get_data_sms($arument1,$argument2,$argument3);`

Comment: $data= $this->debitur->get_data_sms($nama_deb, $no_hp, $tunggakan); like this?

Comment: I forgot to add the message before, I have edited the code.

Comment: doesn't change the answer, you have to supply the arguments the function requires

Comment: when i change the code to: 
$data= $this->debitur->get_data_sms($nama_deb, $no_hp, $tunggakan);
i get this error :
1. Undefined variable: nama_deb, no_hp, tunggakan.
2. Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::getwhere()

Comment: the variables have to be defined before you use them